# How can I edit this custom Wordpress header image?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to change the header/banner of this website but I can't find where to edit it? http://www.healthyonraw.com/

I tried right click to see the path of the logo or banner but it's not giving that info. 
Also tried to see the header.php and css style sheets but can't find it.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: look for header.php in the theme the site is currently using. /wp-content/themes/your-theme/header.php

Comment: that image is handled via css: /wp-content/themes/guylainenou004/images/object1188484082.png - either update that image or update the line of css delivering it

Comment: Thank you Kai Qing, I did that too but can't find where the images or logo is

Comment: Is there no images directory in /wp-content/themes/guylainenou004/

Comment: yes, the images are there. wow, this header is a mess. it's not a whole header, everything was cut piece by =( thank you so much for your help KQ!

Answer (score 1):

To support the comments, Inspecting the element suggests all images would be in the `/wp-content/themes/guylainenou004/images/` directory.

The css file is pointing to this directory so you could either update the image it is referencing or modify the css to point to another image.

Hope it helps.